# git adding subdirectories under the main directory

Tags: git, github, command-line, directory

I have a bunch of projects that I want to be put into a directory under the main directory in git. I am sort of new to git and coding, but I looked for an answer on Google and couldn't find anything. Is it possible that you aren't allowed to add subdirectories to git or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: What is the *problem*? Have you actually *tried* anything? Any why do you want to put multiple projects in one repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can create any number of subdirectories in your git repository (main directory).

When you put projects in git repository, you can simply type in git repository:

```
git add .
git commit -m"comment about my projects"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to create one git repo per project.

When you add *all* your projects in a single git repo, each time you branch or make a tag, that branch or tag will apply to *all* the projects.
If those projects are tightly coupled (ie, you cannot change one without having to change the others), that can make sense.

If those project can evolve independently one from another, it is best to create one repo per project:

```
cd /path/tp/project1
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first commit for project1"
git remote add /url/for/empty/remote/project # GitHub or BitBucket
git push -u origin master

# repeat for project2, ... 
# don't forget to add a README.md per project
```